# Failed to import file excel in Odoo 13. How to?

Tags: csv, odoo, import-from-excel, time-and-attendance, odoo-13

I'd tried to import file excel in module Attendance of Odoo 13.

But I received the error:

Import preview failed due to: year 0 is out of range.

For CSV files, you may need to select the correct separator.

Please help!
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you are doing nothing wrong fault is in the file. Just follow that link you will come to know about how to upload file in Odoo. [LINK](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/user/13.0/general/base_import/import_faq.html)

And import button is removed from odoo13 there is import button in odoo12 in list view.

Comment: Hi Adam, thank you for your support. Yes, I can import the exel file via your link. It just takes a little while to adjust the file to suit Odoo. I am now using the Odoo 13 with import button visible clearly now. I do not know when it was updated? But now I have seen it and am using it to import excel file.

Comment: @Khanh that is nice. And if you think my answer is right please mark it as a correct answer.